# When/Where to call self.update_from_feed_continuously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feedjira

Just a quick question. After watching RailsCasts ep #168 and coming across the following code:

```
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end

  def self.update_from_feed_continuously(feed_url, delay_interval = 15.minutes)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
    loop do
      sleep delay_interval
      feed = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)
      add_entries(feed.new_entries) if feed.updated?
    end
  end

  private

  def self.add_entries(entries)
    entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :name         => entry.title,
          :summary      => entry.summary,
          :url          => entry.url,
          :published_at => entry.published,
          :guid         => entry.id
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm asking myself where/when should I call the method self.update_from_feed_continuously(blah, blah)? Is it going to be in my Feed Controller, or a View (ie Index, show, etc..)

Any help is much appreciated. This question has been bugging me for a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a method to fetch feeds from the input url continuously.

It can be called at anywhere, it depended on the situation.

When you submit the feed url through `controller`, then call the method in `controller`.

When you decide that the feed task should be run regularly, then it can be called by a `rake` task through `whenever`, https://github.com/javan/whenever